# Script that scrapes website infinitely without scraping duplicates doesn't work

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I wrote a simple script, and while it works when scraping the website, when trying to make it not scrape duplicates, it doesn't work. I think the logic to make it not scrape duplicates would be:

1. adding all the links to a list
2. getting new links and comparing to the 1st list
3. if new links in second list aren't in 1st list then amend to the 1st list?

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

f = open("links.txt", "a")
list_=[]

while True:
    try:
        URL = f'WEBSITEURL.COM'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        time.sleep(1)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

        data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'card-content'})
        for div in data:
            links = div.findAll('a')
            for a in links:
                if a not in list_:
                    f.write(a['href'])
                    f.write('\n')
                    print (a['href'])
                elif:
                    continue
    except Exception as e:
        print('something went wrong')
        #continue
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: That's something of the problem. It just triggers my print('something went wrong') error, but looking at the code it should work, in theory? I updated my post with the logic I had when making it

Comment: Raise or print the exception caught so you can actually see what's crashing it.

Comment: Try to print the exception message and see what's wrong: `print('something went wrong', str(e))`

Comment: Note: you're never adding to your list, and if you want to prevent duplicates, use a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `set` is the best built-in data structure for maintaining non-duplicate records. In your case update the set with all links first then write the links to the file.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

list_=set()
while True:
    try:
        URL = f'WEBSITEURL.COM'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        time.sleep(1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'card-content'})
        for div in data:
            links = div.findAll('a')
            list_.update(links)
    except Exception as e:
        print('something went wrong')
        #continue
with open("links.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(list_))
```

If you are still getting `something went wrong` error, then it must not be regarding the links, it is in your scraping code.